# Find last parent for a pipeline

Tags: go-cd

I have two pipelines which after they build one application they trigger another pipeline which contains some tests. I need to know in the child pipeline which one of parent pipelines triggered the tests and set in one variable.

Even if in the child pipeline i have some variables like:
**GO_MATERIAL_1_HAS_CHANGED**, **GO_MATERIAL_2_HAS_CHANGED**, when i trigger the tests by hand by pressing play button, both variables are false. How can I know the last parent pipeline which build the app ?